# How can I handle this datasets to create a datasetDict?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, dataset, nlp-question-answering

I'm trying to build a datasetDictionary object to train a QA model on PyTorch. I have these two different datasets:

```
test_dataset

Dataset({
    features: ['answer_text', 'answer_start', 'title', 'context', 'question', 'answers', 'id'],
    num_rows: 21489
})
```

and

```
train_dataset

Dataset({
    features: ['answer_text', 'answer_start', 'title', 'context', 'question', 'answers', 'id'],
    num_rows: 54159
})
```

In the dataset's [documentation](https://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) I didn't find anything. I'm quite a noob, thus the solution may be really easy. What I wish to obtain is something like this:

```
dataset

DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['answer_text', 'answer_start', 'title', 'context', 'question', 'answers', 'id'],
        num_rows: 54159
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['answer_text', 'answer_start', 'title', 'context', 'question', 'answers', 'id'],
        num_rows: 21489
    })
})
```

I really don't find how to use two datasets to create a dataserDict or how to set the keys. Moreover, I wish to "cut" the train set in two: train and validation sets, but also this passage is hard for me to handle. The final result should be something like this:

```
dataset

DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['answer_text', 'answer_start', 'title', 'context', 'question', 'answers', 'id'],
        num_rows: 54159 - x
    })
    validation: Dataset({
        features: ['answer_text', 'answer_start', 'title', 'context', 'question', 'answers', 'id'],
        num_rows: x
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['answer_text', 'answer_start', 'title', 'context', 'question', 'answers', 'id'],
        num_rows: 21489
    })
})
```

Thank you in advance and pardon me for being a noob :)

Answer (score 21):

to get the validation dataset, you can do like this:

```
train_dataset, validation_dataset= train_dataset.train_test_split(test_size=0.1).values()
```

This function will divide 10% of the train dataset into the validation dataset.

and to obtain "DatasetDict", you can do like this:

```
import datasets
dd = datasets.DatasetDict({"train":train_dataset,"test":test_dataset})
```

Answer (score 12):

For future generations ;)
Adding a bit more information about the answer.

```
from datasets.dataset_dict import DatasetDict
from datasets import Dataset

d = {'train':Dataset.from_dict({'label':y_train,'text':x_train}),
     'val':Dataset.from_dict({'label':y_val,'text':x_val}),
     'test':Dataset.from_dict({'label':y_test,'text':x_test})
     }

DatasetDict(d)
```

Comment: `Dataset.from_dict` is exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I resolved a similar issue while creating a DatasetDict loading data directly from a csv file.
As the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/loading#csv) states, it's just necessary to load the file like this:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files='my_file.csv')
```

If someone needs to load multiple csv file it's possible too.

After that, as suggested by @Lin, an easy method to split by training and validation set is the following

```
train_dataset, validation_dataset= dataset['train'].train_test_split(test_size=0.1).values()
```

Finally, set the DatasetDict like this:

```
dataset = DatasetDict({'train': train_dataset, 'val': validation_dataset})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the answer of @Saha Millis, I manage to combine two different jsonl files into one DatasetDict as follows:

```
test = load_dataset('json', data_files='file1.jsonl')
train = load_dataset('json', data_files='file2.jsonl')
dataset = DatasetDict({'train':train['train'], 'test':test['train']})
```